# How to share article on facebook with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of posts. Click on any post. There is a button to share that article on facebook.
How to develop with ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take time to review the [tour] and [ask]. Show us your search effort and attempts. Try also to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use Facebook Connect [API](http://www.itprotoday.com/web-development/how-use-facebook-connect-api-aspnet-web-application),

- firstly you need to make some request to use this api in your application,
  https://developers.facebook.com/products/sharing
- after it will be approved, you can try to put javascript code wich will try to use use this FB connect api inside of your application, that means it will be processed in client side.

Sorry, but I didnt tryied it jet. But anyway to be able to share some posts, you should be logged like user of FB. Also on official page FB reccomend to use [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)

Comment: Could you make a tutorial, please?